# $f$ is differentiable at any quadratic irrational $a\in (0,\infty)\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. ("How to learn mathematics" edited by Kunihiko Kodaira.)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I am reading "How to learn mathematics" (in Japanese) edited by Kunihiko Kodaira.

Kodaira wrote as follows (I used ChatGPT3.5 for this English translation.):

> I attended Professor Teiji Takagi's lecture on introductory analysis during my first year of university. One of the practice problems was about the continuity of a function $f(x)$  defined as follows: for the interval $x > 0$, if $x$ is irrational, then $f(x) = 0$, and if $x = p/q$ is a rational number (where $p/q$ is in reduced form and $q > 0$), then $f(x) = 1/q$. As is well known, $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x = a$ if $a$ is rational and continuous at $x = a$ if $a$ is irrational. I remember realizing that by slightly modifying the definition of $f(x)$ to $f(x) = 0$ for irrational $x$ and $f(x) = 1/q^3$ for $x = p/q$ (where $p/q$ is a rational number in reduced form with $q > 0$), $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x = a$ if $a$ is rational, continuous at $x = a$ if $a$ is irrational, and further, differentiable at $x = a$ if $a$ is a quadratic irrational. Since then, I began to consider alternative proofs for theorems and to explore variations of problems.

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function such that $f(x) = 0$ for $x\in (0,\infty)\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) =\frac{1}{q^3}$ for $x\in (0,\infty)\cap\mathbb{Q}$, where $x=\frac{p}{q}$ and $\frac{p}{q}$ is in reduced form.

It is obvious that $f$ is not continuous at $a\in (0,\infty)\cap\mathbb{Q}$.
Let $a\in (0,\infty)\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.
Let $\varepsilon$ be an arbitrary positive real number.
Let $N$ be a positive integer such that $\frac{1}{N^3}<\varepsilon$.
Let $d_i$ be the distance between $a$ and the rational number whose denominator is $i$ and which is closest to $a$ for each positive integer $i$.
Let $d:=\min\{d_1,\dots,d_N\}$.
Let $\delta$ be a positive real number such that $\delta<d$.
If $|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|=|f(x)|<\frac{1}{N^3}<\varepsilon$.
So, $f$ is continuous at $a\in (0,\infty)\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

But I cannot prove that $f$ is differentiable at any quadratic irrational $a\in (0,\infty)\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

Please tell me a proof of this fact.

Comment: What do you mean by quadratic irrational ? Something like $\sqrt{2}$ ?

Comment: I am pretty sure that $a>0$ should be an irrational root of a quadratic equation with integer coefficients. Then it suffices to show that for any rational $p/q$ the product $q^{-2}({p\over q}-a)^{-1}$ is bounded, or equivalently $q^2({p\over q}-a)$ is bounded away from $0.$ It can be seen easily for $a=\sqrt{2}.$ Additional power $q^{-1}$ will give the derivative equal $0.$

Comment: Of possible interest is my 13 December 2006 sci.math post titled [Differentiability of the Ruler Function](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/m9SfPUdr4I4/m/kcpzwLqqtJUJ)>. (A search-in-page for "quadratic" shows that quadratic irrational numbers are mentioned in one place.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $r=\sqrt{2}.$
We are going to show
that
$$\lim_{x\to \sqrt{2}}{f(x)-f(\sqrt{2})\over x-\sqrt{2}}= \lim_{x\to \sqrt{2}}{f(x)\over x-\sqrt{2}}=0$$
As $f(x)=0$ for irrational numbers it suffices to consider $x:={p_n\over q_n}\to \sqrt{2},$ where $p_n,q_n\in \mathbb{N}.$
We have
$$\left |{p_n\over q_n}-\sqrt{2}\right |={|p_n^2-2q_n^2|\over q_n(p_n+q_n\sqrt{2})}\ge {1\over q_n^2}$$
Hence $${f\left ({p_n\over q_n}\right )\over \left |{p_n\over q_n}-\sqrt{2}\right |}={1\over q_n^3\left |{p_n\over q_n}-\sqrt{2}\right |} \le {1\over q_n}\to 0$$

The same idea can be applied for any positive irrational quadratic number $r,$ i.e. a solution of the equation $$g(x):=ax^2+bx+c=0,\quad a\in\mathbb{N},\, b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$$ Let $s$ denote the second root of the equation. Clearly $s$ is irrational as well. For any positive  rational number $p/ q$ we have $$0\neq \left |g(p/q)\right |=\left |a(p^2/ q^2)+b(p/ q)+c\right |=q^{-2}| ap^2+bpq+cq^2| \ge q^{-2}$$  WLOG we may assume that $|(p/q)-r|\le 1.$ Then $|(p/q)-s|\le 1+|r-s|. $
We have $g(x)=a(x-r)(x-s).$  Thus
$$|(p/q)-r|={|g(p/q)|\over a|(p/q)-s|}\ge {q^{-2}\over a(1+|r-s|)}$$ Hence
$${|f(p/q)|\over |(p/q)-r|}={q^{-3}\over |(p/q)-r|}\le { a(1+|r-s|)\over q}\to 0,\quad {\rm when}\ {p\over q}\to r$$

**Remark** Let $r$ be an  algebraic irrational number of order $k,$ i.e. $k$ is the smallest positive integer so that $r$ is a root of a polynomial of $k$th degree with integer coefficients. Then $r$ is a single root of that polynomial. It is well known that for any rational number $p/q$ we have
$|(p/q)-r|\ge cq^{-k}$ for a constant $c>0.$ The proof can be performed along the lines above. Therefore for $f(p/q)=q^{-k-1}$ the function $f$ is differentiable at all irrational numbers of order less or equal $k.$

Comment: Ryszard Szwarc, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I have modified the second part in order to make it digestible. I used the symbol $r$ for the quadratic irrational, in order to save $a,b,c$ for some other coefficients.